# How to run code when JMeterThread finishes?

Tags: java, jmeter

In Thread Group I have one thread and two loops.

I need to run code (some cleanup) when the loop ends.

EDIT:

I'm using some proprietary plugin. This plugins stores in queue ids of Threads.
It also stores information which Threads are already in use.

When the loop in Thread Group ends, the information that Thread is used isn't cleared. Thus next loop can't use this Thread and there is only one Thread set per Thread Group.

So I'm looking for a way to clear the info that Thread is used at the end of Thread Group loop.

Comment: Can you show an example and what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Why not add a beanshell processor at the end of your test to perform the clear action?

Comment: @RaGe It's the internal thing of this plugin. I don't want to add any test elements for this plugin to work

Comment: What are you willing to add?

Comment: I don't want to add anything special to test plan for plugin to work. I just need some way to get access to JMeter when Thread Group finishes loop. Then I will remove thread id from used_threads hashmap, and other connection can use this thread

Comment: @rofrol, do you have the source code of the plugin - would like to know when the loop ends?

Comment: I have the source code. I just need to some mechanism to run code when the loop ends. Some JMeter method or similar

Comment: @rofrol, updated my answer. if it is still not clear,  provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `tearDown Thread Group` which will get executed at last to do all the cleanup.

EDIT:

From your updated question & comments, I assume you have the source code of the plugin and would like to clear some information for every iteration.

You need to implement `org.apache.jmeter.engine.event.LoopIterationListener`

You can add this method `iterationStart(LoopIterationEvent loopitr)` 
(there is no `iterationEnd`)

So, JMeter might not know when the loop ends. You can do the clean up (like clearing variables etc) in this method.

---

`loopitr.getIteration()` returns an integer - loop count.

You can do the cleanup as given below (ignoring the first iteration - start from second iteration starting - which is the end of the previous loop -

```
if(loopitr.getIteration()>1){
   // skip the first iteration - start cleaning up from second iteration beginning. 
}
```

However this approach would not clear the last iteration setup.For that you can implement `TestStateListener` which knows when the test ends - you can do the cleanup for the last iteration.

Comment: I've added some clarifiaction. I need to run some code when every loop in Thread Group ends

Comment: Should I add this method to Sampler?

Comment: Nope, in your plugin.